# Running N Iterations of a Single-Processor Job in Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

There should be a simple solution, but I am too novice with parallel processing.

I *want* to run N instances of command `f` in different directories. There aren't different parameters for `f` or anything like that. There are no parameters or anything for `f`. It just runs based on an input file in the directory where it is started. I would like to just run one instance of the function in each of the N directories.

I have access to 7 nodes which have a total of ~280 processors between them, but I'm not familiar enough with mpi things to know how to code for the above.

I *do* know that I can use mpirun and mpiexec, if that helps at all...

Help?

Comment: you do not even need MPI in order to achieve this. A batch manager (SLURM, PBS or other) is all you need here. keep in mind that even if there is no explicit parameter for `f` (e.g. command line option), the current directory in which it is running **is** a (implicit) parameter.

Comment: Hi Gilles (love that name!). Thanks for the response. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it after trying it out!

Comment: I think part of the issue is that I don't know how to specify which core runs which process or how to tell it to use the multiple processors...

Comment: you would typically use a job array, but it would be up to you to link a sub-job (or step) id to a directory.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll look into that! Again, feel free to post all that as answer to be accepted. I appreciate the help! (I also felt bad asking my question so vaguely with no idea where to even start. You've given me some great jumping off points, I think!)

Comment: As @GillesGouaillardet said, you don't need MPI for that. It is just task parallelism without any communication. If you intend to run you N tasks using a job scheduler, you should contact the cluster admin to know which scheduler is installed (usually there is one). Without this information, there is no easy answer.